# If user manipulates the form id what is the best practice to secure it or stop this?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

If user changes the `formID` what should i do to make the `ajax` call and jquery validation success.

```
<form id="formID" action="">



(function ($, W, D) 
{
  var JQUERY4U = {};
  JQUERY4U.UTIL =
  {
    setupFormValidation: function ()
    {
      $("#formID").validate({
        rules: {
          input:"required",


        },
        messages: {
          input: "required",

        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {

         var form = $('#formID')[0];
         var formData = new FormData(form);

         $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/',
          data: formData,
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,

          success: function(data) {

           if (data.response == true) {

             alert('true');

           } else { 

              alert('false');

          }

        },  error: function (jqXHR, exception) {


             console.log(jqXHR.status);
         }
     });


       }
     });
    }
  }
  $(D).ready(function ($) {
    JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
  });

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Why would the user be changing that? Seems like a weird requirement.

Comment: Do you perform server-side validation?

Comment: Nothing at all. If the user changes the value of `id`, and the validation fails, then that would be a correct process for me as the user should NOT be doing that at all.

Comment: Shouldn't matter....your back end must validate all user input anyway. You can't trust anything sent from client

Comment: To build on what @Tigger is saying, a user will always be able to break a website, _for themselves_.

Comment: Yes, I perform server validation, but I return messages in Json so if the user changes the id the response will redirect the user to blank page with Json errors

Comment: Some websites handle this by hiding form inputs, but I don't know how doing something like this

Comment: How does changing the form ID cause it to redirect to a blank page with errors? Can we see your JavaScript code?

Comment: If user goes into console and changes ID...why would they not be surprised when issues arise? Seems like worrying about things that are extreme edge case. Plus they wouldn't have a chance to change it before your plugin initializes

Comment: some thing like this @showdev

Comment: I am just a beginner and looking for best practices to secure my work@charlietfl

Comment: Thanks everybody

Comment: If the user is editing the DOM the website is supposed to break. You might as well ask how to make a form that the user deleted still work. But 1 idea: use a javascript interval to reload (using ajax so that it doesnt look like it is reloading) the entire page every second or so, preserving the user inputs and current focus and sticking them back into the refreshed inputs. Doesn't stop the user from editing the javascript though.

Comment: could any one help me please . should i use [preventDefault()] with submithandler function like one in the example above . thanks @charlietfl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `var form = $('#formID')[0];` in the submitHandler. The form element is already exposed as an argument

The plugin will have already initialized before an ID could be changed by user in console and probably before any userscript or browser extension also

Changing an ID does not affect events already attached to that element.

Beyond that you can't control what a user does in their browser and just need to make sure your back end is secure